# Scala Seq Object to JSON using gson Library

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to do the following:

```
`import com.google.gson.Gson

 object someObject extends App{
      case class entries(a:Seq[String], b:String){
         def toJson() = new Gson().toJson(this)
      }

      val one : Seq[String] = List("m","n")
      val two : String = "ok"

      val ans = entries(a = one, b = two)
      println(ans.toJson)
 }`
```

I am getting the following output:

```
 `{"a":{},"b":"ok"}`
```

Can i know why i am not able to convert the seq to json?
I tried other libraries including spray.json and json4s but no help. Tried a lot over this.

Any help is appreciated. Other similar answers did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Since Gson library is a Java library, I would try to use Java collections instead of Scala collections. With `java.util.List` instead of `scala.collections.Seq` and `java.util.ArrayList`instead of scala List you should get the right output:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.List

object someObject extends App {

  case class entries(a: List[String], b: String) {
    def toJson() = new Gson().toJson(this)
  }

  val one: List[String] = new ArrayList[String]
  one.add("m")
  one.add("n")
  val two: String = "ok"

  val ans = entries(a = one, b = two)
  println(ans.toJson)
}
```

Output now is:

> {"a":["m","n"],"b":"ok"}

Comment: The sequence of string is generated by using .map() method in scala. So I need a way to use it on Scala seq

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
case class Entry(a:Array[String], b:String)
val e = Entry(Array("a", "b"), "c")
val gson = new Gson
println(gson.toJson(e))
```

gson can parse Array type
the output will be:
{"a":["a","b"],"b":"c"}

Answer (score -1):

Try [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala), it supports *all* Scala collections, also it is most efficient serializer to JSON for Scala. Here are [results of benchmarks](http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/oraclejdk8.json) which compare parsing & serialization performance of this library vs. Jackson, Circe and Play-JSON libraries using JDK 8.

Add the library to your dependencies list

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core" % "0.29.2" % Compile, 
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "0.29.2" % Provided // required only in compile-time
)
```

Generate codecs for your case classes, collections, etc.

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._

case class entries(a: Seq[String], b: String)

implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[entries] = JsonCodecMaker.make[entries](CodecMakerConfig())
```

Now you can use it for serialization

```
writeToArray(entries(a = Seq("m", "n"), b = "ok"))
```